# is it possible to read result from readelf command

Tags: c++, c, linux

I was trying to see source file from executables using readelf

```
readelf -s svm_classify| grep FILE
```

gave this result

```
27: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS svm_common.c
30: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS svm_classify.c
31: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
40: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
43: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS
```

now, is that possible to see the content of svm_classify.c?
svm_classify is linux executable

Comment: Not unless you have access to `svm_classify.c`. Do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no. The source code is not embedded into the executable (even if the names of the source files are).

You'll need to gain access to the source code through other means, such as figuring out who has it and asking them nicely.